# Resize UIBarButtonItem in code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

How do I resize a UIBarButtonItem in the code?

Comment: what type of bar button item are you making? system icons or texts?

Comment: Why don't you remove it and allocate a new barbuttonitem with new frame size ?

Comment: It is a Fixed Space Bar Button Item. I will try doing what Legolas suggested, but I'd rather just try to resize the current one using something similar to barButton.something (contentSize?) = CGRect?(width, height). Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change width of a UIBarButtonItem in a UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't resize a UIBarButtonItem as you would a UIView. What you can do is change its **width** property.

```
UIBarButtonItem *b;
// Initialize and such ...
b.width = 150.0;
```

This should work for a Fixed Space Bar Button Item.

Comment: A note on this: I had to also do [toolbar setNeedsLayout] or nothing would happen when I did this in code, where a drawer appeared on the side obscuring the buttons otherwise.

Comment: Why I can't just do this in xib?

Comment: "should work"? Have you definitely done this as it didn't work for me.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988918/change-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-in-a-uinavigationbar/17746858#17746858

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use some custom image in UIBarButtonItem, you can use this code.

```
DoneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[Settings getConfigurableLabel:GENERAL_DONE] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnWorkOrderDoneClicked)];
UIButton *cameraButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
UIImage *cameraImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cameraicon_white.png"];
[cameraButton setBackgroundImage:cameraImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cameraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(openCamera) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem* cameraButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cameraButton];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the UIBarButtonItem's width property to resize the button to fit by setting it to 0.

```
UIBarButtonItem* btn = // init
btn.width = .0f;
```

From Apple's docs:
"If the value is 0.0 or negative, the item sets the width of the combined image and title to fit"
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/width

Comment: Also from the docs: "The default value is 0.0". So this doesn't change anything.