# Setting size of UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize UIBarButtonItem in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950325/how-to-resize-uibarbuttonitem-in-code)

I tried setting the size of the UIBarButtonItem using IB, but in vain

[image]

I want to reduce the width & increase the height. How do I do it? Any pointers please? Setting the width attribute (shown in the figure above) doesn't seem to alter anything. I tried setting it programmatically too like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *historyButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"History" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(history:)];
historyButton.width = 3.0;
```

this too doesn't alter anything.

This is the bar-button (the one in red) that am trying to fix:

[image]

Comment: Should shouldn't be changing the height of the UIBarItem on the UINavigationBar. Food for thought

Answer (score -5):

You need to resize the frame of the UIBarButtonIte

Sth like :

```
historyButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
```

You can see it in this tutorial :

http://iphone-dev-kitchan.blogspot.fr/2010/05/customizing-uibarbutton-on.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, There isn't any 'frame' attribute for the button

Comment: That's why i link the tutorial, check it part 4, start to create a sample button (change his frame, picture ...) and then 

init your UIBarButton with customview 
UIBarButtonItem *CustomBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:MyVCustomWithCustomFrame];

Comment: this didnt work at all. terrible answer. the tutorial specifically says in section 4 "NOT FOR USE IN THE NAVIGATION BAR".

Comment: UIBarButtonItem doesn't have any frame property