# How to set right margin of navigationItem in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -30;
NSArray *rightItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:negativeSpacer,rightBarButtonItem2,rightBarButtonItem1,nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightItems;
```

I hope to adjust the right margin  between rightBarButtonItem2 and the right side of the screen.

It works in iOS 10.

Comment: Can you add image? How exactly you need?

Comment: @Jack I've added a description

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26036553/7576100) which adding custom view on `UIBarButtonItem`